# Does this laundry plumbing vent set-up look correct?

Tags: vent, laundry

Does this look right?

Probably self explanatory but washer on right and sink on left drain into a horizontal 2” PVC drain beneath the slab that then connects into the main drain right before it exits the house. The shared vent runs horizontally along the adjacent wall then goes up a vertical main vent that services only these fixtures and an adjacent basement bathroom (nothing on above floors).

The washer vent set-up is what has me most wary but I welcome any and all thoughts! I have been having epic issues with a contractor and his team that I hired so I am trying to get unbiased third party input where I can.

[image]

Comment: How far away, in total linear feet, is the connection to the shared vertical main vent from the washing machine drain standpipe? The pic does not show this...

Comment: Approximately 23”. That is fine. But i thought a  washer vent had to be separate from the sink? So the washer should have separately vented up before the shared drain connection then looped into the vent used by the sink horizontally

Answer (score 2):

As connected, your washer is wet venting via the sink's drain line.  Practically speaking, this probably won't ever present an issue.  Whether or not it is permitted by your code depends on what codes you are under.

In an open studs situation like this, I wouldn't choose to install it that way, but that doesn't mean it's wrong or bad.  I would do it this way (minus the transition couplings):

[image]